# how to call a function in web page from windows application

Tags: c#, windows, web-applications, httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I have an windows application and also web page application in two different solution and I want When any changes happen in windows application could automatically call "LoadData" method on web page so update page data. how should I do ?
web application is ".net core blazor"
window application is ".net framework c#"
best regards.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]. You need to show us some code to see what you've tried. A "windows application " and a "web page application" can mean so many things, so it's impossible to guess what kind of system you're dealing with.

Comment: web application is blazor web assembly .net core and c# windows application .net framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your windows application has to make an http call to your web application using the `HttpClient` class. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0

Here is the code from the link, I adjusted the URL to the web application to point to your page

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main()
{
    // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions.
    try 
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://you-site/your-page");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
        // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");   
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }
}
```

The line `client.GetAsync("http://you-site/your-page");` will cause your-page to get loaded which will call the page_load function

Comment: this is ok but it effect on windows application and can not call refresh method on web page to effect on web page

Comment: No the HttpClient is equivalent to a browser, so when you call HttpClient GetAsync its like calling the URL with your browser